# heroku login command doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I was trying to create an app with Heroku. Following the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli), I ran `heroku login`, and heroku returned the following error:

```
  !    Invalid credentials provided.
  »   Warning: login is not a heroku command.
 Did you mean join? [y/n]:
  »   Error: Run heroku help for a list of available commands.
  !    Command failed: heroku login
```

My Heroku Version is `heroku-cli/7.0.9 win32-x64 node-v14.11.0`. Any idea why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to instead install it from `npm`, and then run `heroku login` which works.